# Is there way to turn-off auto-tagging of enemies in Far Cry 3's minimap?

Tags: far-cry-3

Right now, whenever an enemy fires at me or gets near me, they show up on the mini-map, as if they were tagged with the camera. With this effect on, not only do I always see exactly where they are, but also the direction they are facing:

[image]

Even worse. Enemies that were "auto-tagged" like that become also semi-visible through walls.

I can live with camera tagging, because that, at least, requires me to scout the area with the camera. This auto-tagging, however, spoils all the surprise ruining the game for me. I always know where the enemy I was fleeing from is and how far away they are.

Looking through options the only option that seemed even remotely relevant was "Weapon tagging" in the Gameplay options alas it doesn't change the "auto-tagged" behavior.

Is there any way to fix this behavior without using a patch to turn the mini-map off completely?

Comment: Have you tried harder difficulty levels?

Comment: @Bora - Nope, didn't. Only the medium one. Why? Is it different on harder difficulties?

Comment: It appears that that screenshot is from (exactly the same as) one of the screenshots I initially took, uploaded and posted in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96799/what-do-the-different-mini-map-highlight-colors-mean). From what I recall, I tagged those enemies with the camera before attacking that outpost (I always did that before attacking).

Comment: @galacticninja - True, I used your image for the sake of example. However, it looks exactly the same even when I don't "tag" the enemies but merely pass close enough to them (or maybe being shot by them?).

Comment: Seems like you don't need the minimap at all, or even the HUD for that matter, if you don't want to see the enemies, why else would you use it??

Comment: @SSH you might have a point there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of patch 1.04, as you found out, you can turn `Weapon Tagging`on/off in the settings, but not the minimap itself, or the *radar* function.

You can turn off the HUD completely, or turn some elements by applying some unsupported patches to your game.  I know, this is not what you asked, but there seems no other way.

[This guide](http://www.gamefront.com/far-cry-3-pc-tweak-guide/#hud) explains how you can apply changes manually.

This [forum thread](http://pcpowerplay.com.au/forums/showthread.php/238094-Far-Cry-3?p=4570140&viewfull=1#post4570140) lists some of these community patches. 
Beware, you might be kicked/banned from Multiplayer games if you play it with these on, so, make a backup of what you are overwriting.

**UPDATE**: The above mentioned patch files are apparently no longer hosted due-to copyright violations.

**UPDATE 2**: You can download the patch (for version 1.04) that removes the enemies from the mini-map [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/c98knm2c/NoEnemy-ASF.html).

Comment: Not perfect, but that's the closest, I guess. Specifically "Disable icons of enemies on the minimap". The filename is "NoEnemy-ASF.rar" if the forum ever goes down. Thanks!

Comment: After playing a bit with "NoEnemy-ASF.rar", it is exactly what I wanted and the game is now a LOT more fun. Thanks again!

Comment: If you can repack your modification and upload it someplace, and better, edit my answer to note the necessary changes, others can be helped too.

Comment: Done. I wasn't sure it is legal on this site, so had to check, [but I guess it is](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266/should-we-allow-links-to-abandonware-game-sites/267#267)

Answer (score 3):

This [forum post, "*How to remove the wallhack tagging when using the camera*" from the Ubisoft forums](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/734046-Mods-for-Far-Cry-3?p=8781800&viewfull=1#post8781800), describes a method to disable "wall hack tagging" (seeing tagged enemies through walls):

> Open the FC3.dll and/or FC3_d3d11.dll (depending on what you use) in any hex editor.
>   Search for the following hex array:
>   53 68 6F 77 54 68 72 6F 75 67 68 57 61 6C 6C 73 41 6C 70 68 61
>
> Change the last value from 61 to 6F, so it reads like so:
>   53 68 6F 77 54 68 72 6F 75 67 68 57 61 6C 6C 73 41 6C 70 68 6F
>
> Lastly, do a search for the following array:
>   53 68 6F 77 54 68 72 6F 75 67 68 57 61 6C 6C 73 00
>
> Change the second to last value from 73 to 6F, so it reads like so:
>   53 68 6F 77 54 68 72 6F 75 67 68 57 61 6C 6C 6F 00
>
> Essentially, you're renaming the commands ShowThroughWallsAlpha to ShowThroughWallsAlpho and ShowThroughWalls to ShowThroughWallo, which nullfies the commands when they're called.

For hex editors, see: https://superuser.com/questions/14465/hex-editors-for-windows

There is also [a mod here that claims to remove wall hack tagging](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/734046-Mods-for-Far-Cry-3?p=8801776&viewfull=1#post8801776).

I found those from this thread, "[Mods for Far Cry 3](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/734046-Mods-for-Far-Cry-3)", in the Ubisoft forums. There are also a couple of [mods or compilation mods (like this one)](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/734046-Mods-for-Far-Cry-3?p=8773981&viewfull=1#post8773981) there that have a feature of removing the mini-map or enemy positions in the mini-map.

From the [Far Cry Nexus](https://www.nexusmods.com/farcry/), the mod, **[HUD annoyances fixed](https://www.nexusmods.com/farcry/mods/7)**, claims to remove enemy icons on the mini-map:

> This mod currently replaces the textures used for the minimap elements and the camera HUD elements in order to improve gameplay and/or remove distracting visual elements. The minimap remains intact because I think functionally it is fine, but I have removed the icons for collectables and enemies from displaying, so that more exploration is needed.

Also from the FC Nexus, there are compilation mods (includes many features) that will either remove wall hack tagging or disable or change the minimap to not include tagged enemies:

[Greetings to Malmo](https://www.nexusmods.com/farcry/mods/37)
[Legit Far Cry](https://www.nexusmods.com/farcry/mods/66)
[Ziggys Mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/farcry/mods/63)
[Poor BastUrd](https://www.nexusmods.com/farcry/mods/4)
[Sleepingwsirens Modpack ReDux](https://www.nexusmods.com/farcry/mods/31)